# Reciprocal of non-continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Is it possible to have a function $f(x)$ not continuous at 0 such that $f(x) + \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is continuous at 0? I've tried to come up with examples but it seems to me that it's impossible.

Comment: If $w = v + \frac{1}{v}$ then $v^2-vw+1 = 0 \implies \displaystyle v = \frac{w\pm (w^2-4)^{1/2}}{2}$. So choose $g(x)$ continuous and let  $f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{g(x)+ h(x) (g(x)^2-4)^{1/2}}{2}$ where $h(x)$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$. You'll get that $g(x) = f(x)+ \frac{1}{f(x)}$ is continuous whereas $f(x)$ is not.

Comment: Are there any simpler examples? I'm in a basic real analysis class and I don't think we would be expected to produce something like that.

Comment: Let  $f(x) = \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ for $x \ge 0$ and $f(x) = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ for $x < 0$...